# How optimistic should I be as someone applying to the University of Helsinki, to the bachelor in science program, from a finance major in the U.S?

Tags: application

I  want to study in Helsinki but I have no idea how I should feel about the admissions process. This switch would essentially change my major from finance to math. My biggest source of apprehension is from the past admissions data. The SAT scores required changes every year and it freaks me out. I feel that I can’t gauge my strength as an applicant. This for undergraduate.

Comment: Did you talk with a counselor at the Helsinki univ to gain insights on your acceptance probability?  There's also an acceptance committee at the univ, so try to touch base with a member to gauge your rank position/likelihood of acceptance.